# Livewire Laravel fetch( `${window.livewire_app_url}/livewire/message/${payload.fingerprint.name}`, probelm

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am seeking for help. Is there any expert solve my Livewire Laravel problem. I am beginner. I installed livewire and follow all rules from livewire , but Its not working .I try to count but its not counting .

Please solve problem.

[When I click + there show Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljnRz.png)

[Here counter.blade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzMKY.png)

[here class Counter extends Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWDMD.png)

[Here welcome.blade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yv3nq.png)

[Here config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjjNg.png)

Comment: can you show the correct blade of component and also the web.php?

Comment: Referencing screenshot of code is not recommended. Try to put minimalistic code in the post

Comment: Hi, please *Do Not* post your code as an image, post is as a text instead. [Here is why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15366635)

Comment: Iam also facing the same error after creating a decent number of projects in laravel.

Wer you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define the route

```
Route::post('/livewire/message' , \App\Http\Livewire\Counter::class);
```